# Reactjs onclick not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import FilterButton from './FilterButton';
import FilterJobsScreen from '../../actions/jobs-screen/FilterJobsScreen';

export default class RightPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counts: {},
            filters: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.load();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.counts) {
            this.setState({
                counts: newProps.counts
            });
        }
    }

    load() {
        this.setState({
            counts: {
                my_jobs: 1,
                not_approved: 5
            }
        });
    }

    onClick (e) {
        alert(e)
        var filters_array = this.states.filters;
        filters_array.push(e);
        this.setState({
            filters: filters_array
        })
        this.context.executeAction(FilterJobsScreen, this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Filters</span>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'My jobs')} name='My jobs' count={this.state.counts.my_jobs} active={true}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Not approved')} name='Not approved' count={this.state.counts.not_approved}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Supply')} name='Supply' count={this.state.counts.supply}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Repair')} name='Repair' count={this.state.counts.repair}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Service exchange')} name='Service exchange' count={this.state.counts.service_ex}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Urgent')} name='Urgent' count={this.state.counts.urgent}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Today')} name='Today' count={this.state.counts.today}/>
                    <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'Overdue')} name='Overdue' count={this.state.counts.overdue}/>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Sorts</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

RightPanel.contextTypes = {
    executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default RightPanel;
```

FilterButton:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FilterButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button className={'btn btn-filter btn-sm'+(this.props.active ? ' active' : '')}><span
                className="filter-name">{this.props.name}</span><span className="filter-count">{this.props.count}</span>
            </button>
        )
    }
}

FilterButton.contextTypes = {
    executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default FilterButton;
```

But when I click on one of my buttons nothing happens at all. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When providing a property to a react component (such as `FilterButton`), this property goes to the `this.props` member of the component. So if you provide an `onClick` property, it can be found in `this.props.onClick` of the component. The property can be any value, e.g. a number or a function. [See here for more information.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html)

In your code, you are providing each of your `FilterButton` an `onClick` property that is the `onClick` method of your `RightPanel` (bound to the `RightPanel` with an argument).
However, the `FilterButton` component itself does not do anything with this property.

I suspect, you want this function to be called when the actual HTML button element of the `FilterButton` component is clicked. To do so, you need to forward this function to the "real" HTML button (i.e. assign it to its `onClick` property).

```
export default class FilterButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
          <button onClick={this.props.onClick} className={'btn btn-filter btn-sm'+(this.props.active ? ' active' : '')}>
            <span className="filter-name">{this.props.name}</span><span className="filter-count">{this.props.count}</span>
          </button>
        )
    }
}

FilterButton.contextTypes = {
    executeAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Do I still need the onClicks in RightPanel? i.e.: <FilterButton onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'My jobs')} name='My jobs' count={this.state.counts.my_jobs} active={true}/>

Comment: Yes. This is how you give `FilterButton` its `onClick` property (`this.props.onClick`).

Comment: I updated my answer with a little bit more details in what is happening.